# is there a regex that only matches a 1 or a 0?

Tags: php, regex, validation

Could someone help me out here I need a regex that only accepts a 1 or a 0 input. for some reason this particular type of regex seems very hard to come by online.

i understand this is easy to monitor with a little PHP but for the particular circumstance that I am in I need a regex

Comment: do you really need regex for this??

Comment: Maybe this - `/^(0|1)$/ ` ?

Comment: If you know the basic rules for creating regular expressions, it should be obvious. Why do you need to search for something like this online?

Comment: @jQuery00 -1 not enough jQuery.

Comment: @jQuery00 Thankyou, thats perfect. as I said in my OP I know I can check this input with PHP but I need regex...thanks again...put it in an answer and I will accept

Comment: @Kevlar I cant't put it as an answer, question holded as off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(0|1)$
```

should match a 0 and a 1 but no other/longer strings.

the important parts are the ^ and $ to mark the beginning/end of the string.

Comment: @HamZa: Now that is just unreasonable. It's anybody's choice whether they want to answer a question for any reason, as long as they're actually trying to answer the question.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't want to downvote. But if everyone answers a question with no showed efforts then the OP will never learn and will ask such questions again. Thus filling SO with bad questions.

Answer (score 1):

This matches a single 0 or 1:

```
^[01]$
```

This matches any number of 0's and 1's:

```
^[01]+$
```

Please go to [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) to learn how to write regular expressions. This is not exactly a complicated RE, as you can see.